# Disabling table animation for ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

The horizontal scrolling animation for ngx-datatable is laggy and I want to disable it. I haven't found any parameters in the docs that would allow me to do this. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable horizontal scrolling add this to the datatable component.

Not sure what animation you are talking about as it's just scrolling on a table. I haven't found it laggy before but I'm sure depending on what you are doing it is possible.

```
[scrollbarH]="false"
```

[Documentation Page](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#horz-vert-scrolling)

[Source Code](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/basic/scrolling.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Remove material from the datatable class

Another option is to check the material class documentations.

https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/readme/themes